# Achieving more than basic labelling of Reference Grids (Graticules, Measured Grids) in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, labeling, grids-graticules

I'm happy to be corrected, but at the moment I do not think it is possible to meet any of the following mapping requirements using either ArcMap or ArcPy:

1. Label measured grids using a format like 6828000mN where 68 is superscript, 28 is normal, 000m is superscript and N is normal
2. Label measured grids using a format that at least enables mN and mE to be included even if all the superscripting above cannot be supported
3. Label graticules using a Degrees, Minutes and Seconds (DMS) format where the minutes and seconds can be written as 00 rather than 0

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to achieve one or more of the above?

Note that I have excluded Grid and Graticule layers from consideration here, because even if they can support these grid and graticule labelling scenarios they are not dynamic and I need the labelling above in a Maps On Demand (MOD) / Data Driven Pages (DDP) like application.

***As an update*** it is possible to do some of 1. and 2. using Corner Labels in a static map as long as it is displayed in a Projected Coordinate System.  However, this hangs ArcMap (and thus prevents it being saved) when the Coordinate System of the Data Frame is switched to Geographic which is necessary for an application like mine that uses a Geographic Coordinate System to determine the appropriate MGA Zone to use for each map at runtime.  Basic labels work for Projected Coordinate Systems just not the fancy ones required in 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. and 2. in the question it is possible to use Corner Labels in a static map as long as it is displayed in a Projected Coordinate System. However, this hangs ArcMap (and thus prevents it being saved) when the Coordinate System of the Data Frame is switched to Geographic which is necessary for an application like mine that uses a Geographic Coordinate System to determine the appropriate MGA/UTM Zone to use for each map at runtime. Basic labels (all numbers in same size font with no units/direction appended) work for Projected Coordinate Systems in the way I need, just not the fancy ones required in 1.

For 3. there is an existing ArcGIS Idea that I recommend you vote for: [Graticule Grid in Layout - Zero Padding In Labels](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/1715)